# PHP MySQL Get the value of a dynamic select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **table item** (`id`, `name`, `content`, `categories id` (foreign key table category)) and a **category table** (`id`, `title`)

- `name`: type text
- `content`: textarea
- `categories_id`: select dynamics related to the category table

Inserting the item table that works very well but in the modification. I have a problem with the dynamic select to the list of categories, not pick me a choice that I chose to add a article.

How I can get the value of the select tag? `<select> <option></option> </select>`

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id ='".$id."'");
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    if (@$_REQUEST['do'] == "update") {
        $m_id = $_POST['id'];
        $nom = $_POST["nom"];
        $contenu = $_POST["contenu"];
        $categories_id = $_POST["categories_id"];

        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET nom='$nom', contenu='$contenu', categories_id='$categories_id' WHERE id =' $m_id' ");

        if($sql)
            header("Location:listArticles.php");
        else
            header("Location:updateArticle.php");
    }  
?>
<html lang="en">
    <body class="nav-md">
        <?php if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $id) { ?>
            <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <table>
                    <td>Nom: <input type ="text" name ="nom" value="<?php echo $res['nom'] ?>"></td>
                    </br>
                    <td>Contenu: <textarea name ="contenu"><?php echo $res['contenu'] ?></textarea></td>
                    </br>
                    <td>
                        Categories:
                        <select class="form-control" name="categories_id" value="<?php echo $res['categories_id'] ?>" >
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name ="do" value="update">Modifier</button>
                    </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                </table>
            </form>
        <?php } ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

That is what the page currently looks like:

[image: Page displaying in browser]

Comment: Please rewrite the first paragraph where you explain your problem using line feeds, and clearly explaining expected behaviour and current behaviour. As it is now, it's unreadable.

Comment: Inside your `?id=` You should put `' OR (TRUNCATE TABLE articles) -- `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and judging by the picture), you want to show the categories and select the category associated with the article.

Here's a rough, untested sketch of how you can approach. Read my comments also.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

// assuming ID is integer, we'll use intval()
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;

// query article matching given ID
$articleRes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id ='" . $id . "'");
$article = mysql_fetch_assoc($articleRes);

// query categories
$categoriesRes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");

// check if form has been submitted
// if you are expecting POST, use $_POST not $_REQUEST
// don't use @, it's sloppy
if (!empty($_POST['do'])) {
    $m_id = $_POST['id'];
    $nom = $_POST["nom"];
    $contenu = $_POST["contenu"];
    $categories_id = $_POST["categories_id"];

    // update article with given ID
    // is it nom or name? 
    $updateRes = mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET nom='$nom', contenu='$contenu', categories_id='$categories_id' WHERE id='$m_id'");
    if ($updateRes) {
        header("Location: listArticles.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: updateArticle.php");
    }
    // good practice to die after you redirect
    die();
}  
?>


<html lang="en">
    <body class="nav-md">
    <?php if ($article) : ?>
    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <table>
            <td>Nom: <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php echo $article['nom'] ?>"></td>
            <!-- you cannot have a BR tag in between TD tags -->
            <!--/br-->
            <td>Contenu: <textarea name="contenu"><?php echo $article['contenu'] ?></textarea></td>
            <!-- you cannot have a BR tag in between TD tags -->
            <!--/br-->
            <td>
                Categories:
                <!-- SELECT tag does not have a VALUE attribute -->
                <select class="form-control" name="categories_id">
                    <!-- loop through the categories and build the OPTION tag -->
                    <!-- for each iteration, check if the category ID matches the article's category ID -->
                    <!-- if so, mark the option as selected -->
                    <?php while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($categoriesRes)) : ?>
                        <option <?php echo $category['id'] == $article['categories_id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $category['title'] ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- unnecessary to have VALUE attribute as this element will always be submitted -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="do">Modifier</button>
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $article['id'] ?>">
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php endif ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Additional points:**

- **Stop using mysql_* functions!** They are deprecated for good reasons. Use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions.
- Your queries are prone to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).
- When mixing PHP control structures (e.g. `if`, `while`, etc) with HTML, I like to use their [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (e.g. `if (condition):` and `endif`; `while (condition):` and `endwhile`; etc). It looks more readable, imo.
- I am using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which is a shorter syntax for simple `if/else` statements.
- Add comments!

Answer (score 0):

Update your update query:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET nom='$nom', contenu='$contenu', categories_id='$categories_id' WHERE id ='$m_id' ");
```

For suggestion:

- use mysqli_*() as mysql_* are depreciated please follow the link: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
- take care of sql injection
- don't suppress the warning using (@)

Comment: If you're going to give an answer with suggestions at least give some good information not half-bothered bullet points